# cx_oracle get input parameters back with keywordParameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using cx_oracle to make db proc calls to our database. We have to strictly avoid positional parameters and use named parameters only in our db calls. The issues is that the document mentions -

> Keyword parameters will be included after the positional parameters
> and are not returned as part of the output sequence.

and so clearly I am not getting the db input parameters back with my call. These input parameters are supposed to be updated and I need the updated values in my further calls to other db procs. [cx-Oracle document](https://readthedocs.org/projects/cx-oracle/downloads/pdf/latest/)

Call 1 with positional parameters -

```
output = connection.cursor() 
result = cursor.callproc("get_some_data", ["name", cx_Oracle.Binary(), output ])
```

returns a list with the updated input/output parameter values.

Call 2

```
output = connection.cursor() 
result = cursor.callproc("get_some_data", keywordParameters = {"input_1":"name", "input_2": cx_Oracle.Binary(), "output":output })
```

returns an empty list, cursor output is available via `output` variable.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: @ChristopherJones, I will but that is a time taking process. Was wondering if someone has a quick workaround which I am missing. cx_Oracle for keywordParameters is not well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the IN OUT and OUT variables, and you know what passed for IN parameters. So you can do anything you want.

```py
"""
create or replace procedure get_some_data(input_1 in varchar2, input_2 in out varchar2, output out sys_refcursor) as
begin
input_2 := input_1 || ' ' || input_2;
open output for select * from dual;
end;
/
show errors
"""

import cx_Oracle
import os

import sys
if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")

username = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME", "cj")
password = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD", "cj")
connect_string = os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING", "localhost/orclpdb1")

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, connect_string)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    output = connection.cursor()
    v = cursor.var(str)
    v.setvalue(0,'Smith')
    result = cursor.callproc("get_some_data", keywordParameters = {"input_1":"Fred", "input_2": v, "output":output })
    print(v.getvalue())
    for row in output:
        print(row)
```

gives:

```
Fred Smith
('X',)
```

Comment: Ah, I was looking in a completely different direction and ignored this simple option. Thanks a lot.